# as.Date returns N/A, string is %d/%m/%Y, & locale solutions do not change output in R

Tags: r

Used read.csv to import a Quicken for Mac CSV export file to make a dataframe in R:

```
> str(datQ)
'data.frame':   443 obs. of  4 variables:
$ V2: chr  "IBM" "IBM" "IBM" "IBM" ...
$ V6: chr  "1" "1" "4" "1" ...
$ V7: chr  "184.42" "187.04" "660.56" "178.44" ...
$ V1: chr  "7/10/2009" "7/13/2009" "7/30/2009" "8/18/2009" ...
```

Running as.Date like so returns a vector of NA.

```
> as.Date(datQ$V1, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] NA NA NA ...
```

A manually created DF works, so the error is specific to the datQ df:

```
> df <- data.frame(date = "7/10/2009")
> as.Date(df$date, format= "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2009-07-10"
```

I've also played around with locale, like so:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME")
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
> as.Date(datQ$V1, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
  [1] NA NA NA...
```

So the question is, why is the imported CSV data failing like it is? I've already run a trimws over the datQ dataframe to cleanup leading/trailing whitespace etc.

Any ideas?

Edit: Per request adding more data about the problematic datQ df...

```
> dput(head(datQ))
structure(list(V2 = c("IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", "IBM", 
"IBM"), V6 = c("10", "10", "40", "10", "1", "1"), V7 = c("184.42", 
"187.04", "660.56", "178.44", "221.40", "218.41"), V1 = c("7/10/2009", 
"7/13/2009", "7/30/2009", "8/18/2009", "9/22/2008", 
"9/23/2008")), row.names = c("6", "7", "8", "9", "11", "12"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit edit: so a commenter was able to get as.Date working on my dput output. I took a look at head(datQ) and then copied the onscreen output to the console. Right before the date value, RStudio shows a PINK box with a period in it. Has anybody seen something like this?

[image: Weird pink box in console copy paste data]

Comment: Could you please share your data with us? Edit you question with `dput(head(datQ))` output. Yep, it is kind of strange, but you will be sharing the first six lines of you data frame exactly how R have read them.

Comment: @MarcusNunes added for your reference

Comment: I tried to run the same command you used and I got the expected result: `as.Date(datQ$V1, format = "%m/%d/%Y")` gives me `"2009-07-10" "2009-07-13" "2009-07-30" "2009-08-18" "2008-09-22" "2008-09-23"`.

Comment: @MarcusNunes thanks. I think I'm dealing with a non-printable character or some other garbage in the data. I will update the question with more observations. I've googled what I'm seeing but no joy so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @MarcusNunes help, I figured out that there was a non-printable, non-visible, non-UTF8 character at the head of the date value in the Quicken for Mac CSV export file. Having run trimws over the data did not remove this garbage character. Copying and pasting the data from RStudio back into the RStudio console showed me a weird pink box with a period in it right before the date. This tipped me off that something like this might be causing the problem. Doing the same to my sample DF did not show a pink box.  See this URL for where I picked up reference code:

https://rpubs.com/Mentors_Ubiqum/Clean_Text

This code works on my machine:

```
> as.Date(datQ[1, 4], format = "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] NA
> as.Date(gsub("[^[:alnum:][:blank:]?&/\\-]", "", datQ[1, 4]), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2009-07-10"
```

Comment: Great. I'm glad that I've helped you.